# Does Buildout support value substitution in the extends option?

Tags: python, buildout

Does [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/) support [value substitution](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/topics/variables-extending-and-substitutions.html#value-substitutions) in the `extends` option of the `buildout` section?

For example, this `example.cfg` doesn't extend with `base.cfg`:

```
[config]
base = base.cfg

[buildout]
extends =
    ${config:base}
parts =
```

---

```
buildout -c example.cfg annotate
```

---

My goal is to send the file-to-extend as a *parameter* from the outside like this:

```
buildout config:base=base.cfg -c example.cfg annotate
```

I tried to [merge](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/topics/variables-extending-and-substitutions.html#merge-values-with-existing-values) the `buildout:extends` from the outside; but that doesn't work either:

```
buildout buildout:extends+=base.cfg -c example.cfg annotate
```

Comment: Since I am writing everything in a bash script, I did template substitution using `envsubst` to get the same effect. Probably, I need to switch to Python though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `extends` doesn't support value substitutions, unfortunately. The current implementation processes `buildout.extends` before variable substitution can take place.

There is an existing feature request open for this: [#39 *No variable substitutions in extends*](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/issues/39).

I generally create a `local.cfg` file first, perhaps from a template, and run `buildout -c local.cfg`. That'd be the kind of place I'd put custom extends configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that *order* matters for `extends`. Need to dig deeper into the code though.

Comment: @Nishant: `extends` is [handled inside `_open()`](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/9418699ca136e7eb21629712766f999ea14147f6/src/zc/buildout/buildout.py#L1809-L1827). `_open()` is called to [load the configuration file for the `Buildout()` instance](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/9418699ca136e7eb21629712766f999ea14147f6/src/zc/buildout/buildout.py#L366-L370), which eventually [sets `self._raw` from the merged results](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/master/src/zc/buildout/buildout.py#L436).

Comment: @Nishant: `self._raw` is used in [`__getitem__`](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/master/src/zc/buildout/buildout.py#L1310-L1325) to create `Options()` instances per section, and only [then, in `Options._initialize()`](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/master/src/zc/buildout/buildout.py#L1419-L1422), are value substitutions processed.

Comment: I did check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77226/award-extra-points-to-answer, but I can't figure out how to offer extra points.

Comment: How do I offer extra bounties for this answer? This was like a tip of iceberg for me and I was given a proper answer including GitHub PR for an existing question. Is there some way to offer some bounties like 100 points for this answer?

Comment: @Nishant I’m glad you found this to be helpful! See [Can't we award bounty to a helpful answer directly?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306182) for the details on how you can award a bounty to an existing answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Martijn! I have added a bounty.